# need help creating a SELECT query to select unique rows

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

I want to create an SQL Query for a **SQLite3 DB**.

In my table I have the following sample data

```
7/1/2011   8:02   LOGIN   JOE
7/1/2011   8:15   LOGIN   CAROL
7/1/2011   8:15   LOGIN   JOE
7/1/2011   8:35   LOGIN   SANDY
7/1/2011   13:15  LOGOFF  SANDY
7/1/2011   16:15  LOGIN   SANDY
7/1/2011   18:12  LOGOFF  CAROL
7/1/2011   21:09  LOGOFF  TED
7/1/2011   21:19  LOGIN   TED
7/1/2011   22:10  LOGOFF  JOE
7/1/2011   23:40  LOGOFF  SANDY
7/2/2011   9:00   LOGIN   JOE
7/3/2011   10:00  LOGIN   JOE
7/3/2011   20:00  LOGOFF  SANDY
```

basically I want to only get the first LOGIN entry per date and the last LOGOFF entry for the same date (if available)

So I want the query to produce

```
7/1/2011   8:02   LOGIN   JOE
7/1/2011   8:15   LOGIN   CAROL
7/1/2011   8:35   LOGIN   SANDY
7/1/2011   18:12  LOGOFF  CAROL
7/1/2011   21:09  LOGOFF  TED
7/1/2011   21:19  LOGIN   TED
7/1/2011   22:10  LOGOFF  JOE
7/1/2011   23:40  LOGOFF  SANDY
7/2/2011   9:00   LOGIN   JOE
7/3/2011   10:00  LOGIN   JOE
7/3/2011   20:00  LOGOFF  SANDY
```

As you can see we are interested in the first login and the last logoff for a user.

**All fields are separate fields that are stored as a VARCHAR()
EXCEPT DATE and TIME**
The date is stored as DATE
The time is stored as TIME
Below are the field names and what they represent.

```
tddate - date
tdtime - time
tdtype - LOGIN/LOGOFF
tdusername - username
```

Not all login have a corresponding logoff because a person may disconnect from the network without actually logging off.

Here is a query that I was attempting to use

```
select tddate,
        case tdtype
                   when 'LOGIN' then Min(tdtime)          
                   when 'LOGOFF' then Max(tdtime)        
                   end as tdtype  from TimeData                     
WHERE tdusername LIKE "JOE"
```

i get 0 rows of data

Comment: Why is tdtime and tddate seperated and more important: why is it varchar?

Comment: how can i "convert" it without losing data?

Comment: Are you sure that JOE should be in double quotes? Also, clarity might be better if you didn't have the same label for both columnns ('tdtype' for both the case and after, on its own). Oh, and a Group By on tddate and tdtype would be good...

Comment: @Jabob - I am not sure. I was just trying different things to see if I would get results.

Comment: The word "unique" in title may be misleading - more like "first and last records by user by date"?

Comment: Yes. The first LOGIN and LAST logoff per user by date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have almost works like you want. You just need to add a group by clause:

```
SELECT
    tddate,
    CASE tdtype
        WHEN 'LOGIN' THEN MIN(tdtime)
        WHEN 'LOGOFF' THEN MAX(tdtime)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS tdtime,
    tdtype,
    tdusername
FROM TimeData
GROUP BY tddate, tdtype, tdusername
ORDER BY tddate, tdtime
```

Comment: Why is the first entry tdtime always showing up as NULL? I checked the data to see if it really was null but its not.

Comment: My guess is that you have an extra space-character there. It is neither equal to `'LOGIN'` nor `'LOGOFF'`, so it has to be something else.

Comment: When I run a simplier query (SELECT tdtime, tddate, tdtype FROM TiMEDATA WHERE tdusername LIKE "JOE" ORDER BY tddate, tdtime ASC); I get all the data in the fields.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM TimeData WHERE tdtype NOT IN ('LOGIN','LOGOFF')`

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to either self-joins or unions as well as result partitioning to make this work:

```
   SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DateField
        , TimeField
        , ActionField
        , UserField
        , RealDate = Max(CAST(DateField + ' ' + TimeField AS DateTime))
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserField, ActionField ORDER BY Cast(DateField + ' ' + TimeField AS DateTime) DESC)
FROM   theTable
WHERE  ActionField='LOGOFF'
GROUP BY Datefield, TimeField, ActionField, UserField
UNION
SELECT DateField
        , TimeField
        , ActionField
        , UserField
        , RealDate = Max(Cast(DateField + ' ' + TimeField AS DateTime))
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserField, ActionField ORDER BY Cast(DateField + ' ' + TimeField AS DateTime) DESC)
FROM   theTable
WHERE  ActionField='LOGIN'
GROUP BY Datefield, TimeField, ActionField, UserField) AS Result
WHERE Result.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY UserField, RealDate
```

EDIT: Nevermind - I didn't realize this was SQLite.  There's no row_number function there.  You might need temp tables...

Answer (score 0):

```
select tddate, max(tdtime) time, tdtype, tdusername 
from table 
where tdtype = 'LOGIN' 
group by tddate, tdtype, tdusername

union

select tddate, min(tdtime) time, tdtype, tdusername 
from table 
where tdtype = 'LOGOUT' 
group by tddate, tdtype, tdusername
```